# Using Resource Parameters to develop a query area based on direction

Tags: here-api

Can anyone suggest a method to use HERE Resource Parameters and/or other filter to determine a map query area that is **based on direction of travel**, in order to check that area for "flow" or "jam factor"?

I envision something using the geospecial filters, but not sure about the approach to use so that the query is based on direction of travel.

Apologies if this is something elementary.  I am a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/topics/request-constructing.html) and [examples](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/traffic) of the Traffic API already?

Comment: Appreciate the reference! Appears to be good information at the links you refer to. I think the real question is how to dynamically determine what coordinates to use in a HERE query. I want to dynamically determine coordinates for a corridor that is ahead of the direction of travel.